# How to start a program using the keyboard when task bar isn't at the bottom?

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-preview

I just noticed that whenever the task bar (the thing where <kbd>Win</kbd> and the clock reside isn't at the bottom (I prefer to keep it at the top or to the right), I can't type in the name of the program that I wish to execute.

When it's placed at the bottom and I start typing, the entered string filters against installed applications, settings etc. How can I make the computer do it so even when the task bar isn't at the bottom?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10, you can use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to activate the search functionality directly, regardless of taskbar orientation.

Comment: Not quite an answer to the question. In fact, when I tried it, it doesn't even work. The search window doesn't appear on the screen (when the task bar is at the top, that is). I believe the search mode is entered but the problem is that it doesn't show. Just by pressing Win and start typing I get the result I want **but only** when the task bar is at the bottom of the screen. More suggestions?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's still a bit glitchy, but if you hit `Win` then `Win + S` then the search should show up, or you might just have to wait until they fix it.

Comment: It **did** work in Win 8. How can it "go back" to undone in Win 10=! I dislike waiting for good stuff, hehe. Darn... :(